# Horizontal Scroll Bar in Pocket Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, mobile

For my project I need to show a horizontal scroll bar in the Pocket Internet Explorer (PIE). The best discussion I could find on the web is at http://www.pocketpcjunkies.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/pocket-pc/31244/Horizontal-scroll-only-PIE which does not have a clear solution. Can you please give me some directions on how to do it? I am open to using any HTML (and/or CSS) element inside the web page as long as I can show the horizontal scroll bar in the PIE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `overflow` property specifies what happens if a content overflows an element's box. You could have container `div` (or any blocking tags) with a fixed width, and set `overflow` to `scroll` or `auto`, for example:

```
  <div style="width: 320px; overflow: scroll">
  ...
  </div>
```

For *One Column* view, try adding `white-space: nowrap`.

There was a registry hack to make PIE pretend to be a desktop browser, see [How to make PIE to pretend to be a desktop browser](http://www.smartphonemag.com/cms/forum/topic/17223?&TOPIC_ID=17223).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your solution works but only if I select  Menu -> View -> Desktop, in PIE. If I select Menu -> View -> One Column, in PIE, it is not working. I think I will use your solution and use the "Desktop" option in PIE to show the scroll bar for now. If anyone finds a way to automatically set the option to "Desktop" in PIE or show a horizontal scroll bar in "One Column" mode of PIE please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: For One Column view, try adding `white-space: nowrap`.